# MySQL: How do I search by timestamp but convert timezone first?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to be able to get the total amount spent either monthly or daily. To do that I do `sum(tblaccounts.amountin)` but the issue i'm having is I need to convert my `date` column to a different timezone fist. I've tried messing with `convert_tz(date,"+00:00","+10:00")` but not sure how to use it with `LIKE`.

How can I get records for monthly or daily based on the `$period` variable while first converting the timestamp?
Something like `WHERE convert_tz(date) LIKE $date_to_check%`

```
function check_limit($period='monthlylimit') {

    if ($period == 'monthlylimit') {
        $date_to_check = date("Y-m");
    }
    else { ### Day period
        $date_to_check = date("Y-m-d");
    }

    $select = "SELECT
        sum(tblaccounts.amountin) as amountin
    FROM tblaccounts
    WHERE date LIKE '" . $date_to_check . "%'";
}
```

Comment: You should be storing into the table as UTC, then convert the times for your range into UTC for your query.  It's very wasteful to fixup the timestamp for every record instead of just the one value.

Comment: @DaveS I am storing them as UTC but the conversion needs to happen for this query.

Comment: I'm saying fix $date_to_check in PHP before supplying it to your query.  If it is already UTC then MySQL doesn't need to convert_tz

Comment: I'd go with Dave's suggestion on making a time that matches whats already in the database. But personally, this is all why I store times as a unix timestamp int, instead of a datetime field ;)

Comment: Date time field is much more verbose and easy to work with and if you store all dates as UTC you should be fine anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing the timezone change inside mysql, this should work out:

```
if ($period == 'monthlylimit') {
    $date = date('Ym');
    $format = '%Y%m';
} else {
    $date = date('Ymd');
    $format = '%Y%m%d';
}
$sql = "SELECT SUM(t.amountin) as amountin FROM tblaccounts t WHERE 
        DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(t.date,'+00:00','+10:00'),'". $format ."') = '". $date ."'";
```

The correct timezone numbers, will depend on what you have mysql defaulted too, and your desired result. You may have to twiddle with that number.

---

Or you can change the timezone for the date on php's side and skip mysql tz converting:

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz));// $tz to equal what you are aiming for
$dt->setTimestamp(time());// might not be needed
if ($period == 'monthlylimit') {
    $date = $dt->format('Ym');
    $format = '%Y%m';
} else {
    $date = $dt->format('Ymd');
    $format = '%Y%m%d';
}
$sql = "SELECT SUM(t.amountin) as amountin FROM tblaccounts t WHERE 
        DATE_FORMAT(t.date,'". $format ."') = '". $date ."'";
```

*Note:* I did not use `LIKE` here, as that is why I introduced `DATE_FORMAT` to set it to a single value to compare on.